# HTML5 "required" attribute not working before submit validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing an assignment with JavaScript and I have to make a quiz. My problem is I'm using the HTML 5 "required attribute" on my radio buttons. The problem is when I use an onclick event for the submit button it disregards the required attribute and executes the function to display a new question/choices. So if the radio buttons aren't selected it still performs the onclick event.

I'd like it so the required attribute checks if the radio buttons are checked before the onclick event.

I'm just not sure how to do this.

I display my radio buttons like this

```
  var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.id = i;
    radio.value = i;
    radio.name = "option";
    radio.required = true;
```

Here is my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VodkaTonic/4FJmU/

Comment: Are you allowed to use JQuery...

Comment: Yes I can, but I'd rather learn by using pure JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attached an `onclick` event to the go to the next question, form validation is only preformed on submit. Instead attach it to the `onsubmit` event of the form:

```
quiz.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkAnswer(currentQuestion);
}
```

A couple of other things...

CSS [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) such as `id` can not start with a digit, you need to prefix it with a letter:

```
radio.id = 'r' + i;
```

(you'll also need to update them in the `getElementById` calls in `checkAnswer`)

Your labels don't work correctly either. `for` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript. Unfortunately reserved words can't even be used as dot properties of objects (if you are making your own object you could set/get it using the bracket notation `obj["for"]`, but not dot notation `obj.for`). For this reason the for attribute of DOM nodes is accessed via `.htmlFor`:

```
    label.htmlFor = radio.id;
```

There are a few others like this to watch out for, the most common of which would e `.className` to access the `class` attribute of DOM nodes.

[Fiddle with these fixes](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/X3gc9/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are binding an onClick method to the submit. The onClick will trigger and process BEFORE the onSubmit, which results in it getting past the validator. Try changing the onclick to onsubmit like this:

```
nextButton.onsubmit = function() {
    checkAnswer(currentQuestion);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FJmU/4/)

Note, you will probably need to cancel the actual form submit, since you aren't sending any data anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**WORKING**

http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/4FJmU/3/

you must use FORM.onsubmit

```
/*nextButton.onsubmit = function() {
      checkAnswer(currentQuestion);
}*/

quiz.onsubmit = function() {
      checkAnswer(currentQuestion);
      return false;
}
```